# Viewport meta tags vs Media Queries?

Tags: html, css

I would love to know, to optimize your website for Tablets, desktops and smarthpones, what is best to use: Media Queries or the Viewport meta tags? see code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

vs

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that you can only choose to use one out of the two.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE: from 2020**

You'll want a viewport meta tag (always)

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

and almost always a few @media break-points

but often (lately) - people try and leverage things with percentage, variable/relative units, flex-box, and auto-fill type grid situations to avoid @media queries

I think that all of those things can just work together for the best results. I like @media queries for many reasons. : ) They are all just tools to use! Stick to the goals - and the right tools will present themselves.

Here's [a video](https://vimeo.com/478753228) that goes over the whole thought process.

And here's [an article](https://www.codementor.io/@sheriffderek/basics-of-responsive-design-media-css-at-rule-du107krxa) about the @media rule.

.....

(original answer for back-story)

i would say that every situation is different... and it is not an either / or situation.  the viewport meta tag you have up there would make it so that the website will maintain the 1 to 1 ratio which in a lot of cases is good.  however, it also is set user-scalable "no" - and that means that the user will not be able to zoom in etc... sometimes the way ipads and other devices change your site is for the best... (depends)

the best method i have found is to use media queries and to choose one of 2 dirrections:

1. start from small and build up
2. start from large and build down

stretch your browser window bigger and bigger (or smaller and smaller) and then when the website gets ugly, (just before) that is your next breakpoint... make the media query there... and repeat.  don't pay attention to all of the device sizes --- this way you'll know that no matter what new devices etc come out --- you have engineered it to look nice at every possible size.  (when it gets under 320 / i like to just make the site turn into a business card/// better to have readable info for none smart-phones...)

then after all this... test on devices and try out different viewport meta tags.

there are a lot of great articles about it... use keywords like "responsive design" or "adaptive" or "RWD"  responsive web design.  and good luck !!!

Comment: ps - be weary of jQuery media sensing stuff... because they won't adjust when you change desktop browsers size... but they can be great for targeting mobile devices etc...

Comment: one more thing... some old browsers don't see the media queries... but there is a jQuery that will teach them to see it... so check that out...

Comment: also --- if you embed videos... i've really been loving "Fitvids"  it's a plugin that tells vimeo etc.. to adapt and change sizes to fit the div... it is RADICAL !!! just like Chris Coyier and Paraval...

Comment: Tell me another thing please, what is best, to have a normal fixed-value defined css style, and then set all your other css queries to relative percentile widths/heights of that 'normal' stylesheet? Or to define each media query stylesheet with its own fixed dimensions?

Comment: well... again... it is situational...  for example...  a newspaper like site might have everything fixed width... but that's because they have tons of text.  In my experience... percentages are great.... but they leave blocks of text without a ton of control.  The only people who are really scaling the browser up and down are designers... most people open a web page and whatever size that is... it stays there...

Comment: What i do now, is to make 6 break points... and then to use css transitions to flow in-between...  http://derekthomaswood.com/transitionV.1/trans2.html  i've been working on an example for clients... (still really rough)

Comment: Thank you for this, it saved me hours of debugging!!

Comment: Made this recently - for people who are new to the idea of responsive layouts: https://vimeo.com/478753228

Answer (score 23):

Both are necessary.

**Media queries** are used to have different css for different devices its like the if condition for different devices.

**Viewport** meta tag is to set tell the device to take the width according to this tag. Its like a reset for devices if its not used device will adjust the layout according to its default settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tell me, what is best, to have a normal fixed-value defined css style, and then set all your other css queries to relative percentile widths/heights of that 'normal' stylesheet? Or to define each media query stylesheet with its own fixed dimensions?

Comment: Its better to design for mobile first & move ahead for larger devices. Percentage with layout or liquid layout is best for any kinda design it will be good if you are able to handle that. Or other way is u can have adaptive layout with fixed width for all different resolutions.

Comment: thank you. So if I understand correctly, there is adaptive layout(fixed widths for media queries) and Responsive layout(fluid percentile widths for media queries).

Comment: I would say: Both are NOT necessary... HTML is responsive by default. Love the rest of your answer.

Answer (score 9):

It depends what do you want to achieve.

If you want to design for desktop resolution only and have the mobile browser "zoom out"and assume a desktop like resolution than you can use only the viewport meta tags, setting the width to a fixed value.

If you want a true responsive design you should set the viewport meta tags to device-width and use media queries to plan the layout for different resolutions as you have shown in your code.

Comment: one question, I have a an image which is my main webpage image, and it centers the page. Now I want the height to always flow with the screen size, such that you should never scroll. How this change the situation since everything is designed/specified in terms of widths?

Answer (score 0):

@Media Query use to Response our web site for other devices.
For example this query only works for devices with min 768px width and devices with max 1024px.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

**What is a Media Query?**
It uses the @media rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true.

Example
If the browser window is 600px or smaller, the background color will be lightblue:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

**What is the Meta View port???**

The viewport is the user's visible area of a web page.

The viewport varies with the device, and will be smaller on a mobile phone than on a computer screen.

Before tablets and mobile phones, web pages were designed only for computer screens, and it was common for web pages to have a static design and a fixed size.

Then, when we started surfing the internet using tablets and mobile phones, fixed size web pages were too large to fit the viewport. To fix this, browsers on those devices scaled down the entire web page to fit the screen.

This was not perfect!! But a quick fix.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I hope this may help you to understand about meta viewport and @Media query.

Answer (score 0):

Don't underestimate either one!
You need:

- Viewport meta to make your text actually readable
- MQs to make your web page easy to use on small screens