# difference between fluid grid and media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, fluid-layout

I'm very new to responsive web design, so please excuse me for this dumb question.
I have to build an existing desktop website to responsive design. After googling I have found two ways - Fluid grid and Media queries. However I'm confused which approach I should follow or do I need to use both to develop responsive site. 
As per my understanding, Fluid grid is used to display webpages according to different viewport but media queries is used to put different content(images, text) according to the room available in different sizes of browser (making browser smaller manually or from mobile/tablet/desktop browser). Please correct me if I am missing something here.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to understand is that all responsive layouts always use css to resize the page.

its all at the end the same.

Media Queries detect the size of the browser and loads in additional css.

OR

Viewport load in css based on the device width

```
@viewport {
width: device-width;
}
```

essentially the easiest way to approach a layout if its simple is to make it fluid/100% width 
and as you need more customization add media queries like this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 960px){
your css in here
}
```

its all css, like loading a different set of css files by detecting browser/browser-size/browser-type/device/ device width.

there are no rules!

Comment: still my original question is not answered :( In which senerio I will use fluid grid layout, in which senerio I will use Media quiries and in which senerio I will use both.

Comment: and the answer is not an this either this OR that situation...
Read this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510232/viewport-meta-tags-vs-media-queries

Answer (score 4):

Basically, fluid grid systems will give you some flexibility within a small resolution range, but to create a responsive layout, that works for a wide range of devices, you have to use media queries. You use a grid system mainly to provide a structure to your layout. Responsive grid systems can use both media queries and a grid system. These are two different technologies with different objectives.

You have to know some history to understand this. Fixed grid systems came first and the most popular setup was: 960px width divided into 12 or 16 columns. These evolved into fluid grid systems. When they were created and used, display resolution ranged from 1024px to 1920px and their purpose was to bring some flexibility to this relatively small resolution range. The most important role of a grid systems (fixed or fluid) is to provide a structure base for your layout/design.

Media queries were created for a much wider resolution range - from mobile, tablet to plasma screens. Their primary objective in RWD is to detect the type of device and provide alternative styling for each device.

There is no one solution for using both grid systems and media queries as they have different primary objectives.

The problem in using both these technologies is: imagine a 300px wide screen divided into 16 columns (in a 16 column grid system). The columns become quite narrow.

So, what is the solution? Modern and responsive grid systems can stack groups of columns on top of each other (using media queries). CSS classes can also be used to change the number of columns, or to hide certain elements of the layout depending on the device (which is detected using media queries).
These two, different technologies can be used together to bring structure to the layout (grid system) and provide the best user experience all kinds of devices (media queries).