# CSS equivalent of <meta name="viewport">

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

So I have a bit of a unique problem with a closed website system.

I can edit the CSS, but am unable to do major HTML changes to the site, which includes the usual.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 />`

Which would normally handle a responsive view of our website.

My question then is, would it be possible to achieve the same effect, through a Css sheet.

Any and all assistances will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can HTML META tag be modified in CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42515881/can-html-meta-tag-be-modified-in-css-file)

Comment: neither the question (trying to modify the metatag with css) nor the accepted solution is what im asking about.

i specificly need a way to handle initial scale, and device-width in css form and none of the solutions ive come across have worked.

Comment: "My question then is, would it be possible to achieve the same effect, through a CSS sheet", I understood you were trying to achieve the same thing, apologies. Could you be a bit more precise then ?

Comment: Do you really intend to do this using CSS sheets, or maybe you can consider doing this using javascript/jquery? Just append this `meta` tag in your `head` element

Comment: thats the challenging part of the problem, i cannot change head or body elements in any major way, which is why i was looking for a pure css solution as that is something i can change, though i believe a javascript should also be posible, could you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

There is [`@viewport`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/#atviewport-rule), but it has already been deprecated. Apparently browsers did not feel like implementing it.

More information: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4766